# Python Heap, Hydra

Tags: python, heap

This is a simulation program, where Hercules fights the Hydra, and it consists of rounds. If lets say Hercules beats Hydra, it should output `Result: Hercules defeats Hydra in "i" rounds.` If it goes for more than 100 rounds then it should output: `Hydra defeated Hercules`. The next thing is: if the head size after each round is 1, the it passes. If the head size is greater than one, then it adds size of "headsize//2" to grow back in its place. This is just a little clue of what the simulation should be like.

```
from array_heap import*

###################################################################
#Function for the file reader                                     #
###################################################################

def file():
    """
    Opens the file and reads it for the simulation
    """
    fileName = input("Enter file name: ") 
    fp = open(fileName)
    line = fp.readline()
    stat = fp.readline()
    stat = stat.strip()
    initHydraHeads = []
    for i in range(len(stat)):
        initHydraHeads.append(int(stat[i]))
    growHydraHead = fp.readline()
    return line, initHydraHeads, growHydraHead


###################################################################
#Starting the simulation                                          #
###################################################################

def HydraHeadStartOfGame(initHydraHeads, line):
    """
    Takes 2 arguments:
       initHydraHeads
       line
    Returns an instance of the hydra head initially
    """

    if line == "largest":
        choise = greater
    else:
        choise = less
    hHead = mkHeap((len(initHydraHeads) + 100), choise)
    for i in range(len(initHydraHeads)):
        add(hHead, initHydraHeads[i])
    return hHead

def HydraHeadGrowBack(headsize, hHead):
    """
    HydraHeadGrowBack function makes the head grow twice in size if the headsize is greater than 1
    """

    if headsize == 1:
        pass
    else:
        for i in range(2):
            newHeads == headsize//2
            add(hHead, newHeads)
    return hHead

def headGrowbyOne(hHead, i):
    """
    Makes the head grow by one after each round
    """

    if i == 0:
        pass
    else:
        for i in len(hHead.array):
            hHead.array[i] += 1
    return hHead


def main():
    line, initHydraHeads, growHydraHead = file()
    print("Hercules' strategy: ", line)
    print("Initial Hydra Heads: ", initHydraHeads)
    print("Hydra growth period: ", HydraHeadGrowBack)
    hHead = HydraHeadStartOfGame(initHydraHeads, line)
    #print(removeMin(hHead))

    i = 0
    while i < 100: #100 means 100 rounds
        headGrowbyOne(hHead, i)
        if hHead.size == 0:
            print("Hercules wins, Hydra is dead!")
            print("Result: Hercules slays the hydra after ", i, "rounds")
            break;
        else:
            print("Current size: ", hHead.size)
            severedHead = removeMin(hHead)
            HydraHeadGrowBack(severedHead, hHead)
            print(hHead.array)
        i += 1

main() #run the program
```

As an example this is how the output should look like:

```
Please input name of file to read: hydra.txt
Hercules' strategy: smallest
Initial Heads: [8, 7, 3]
Hydra Growth Period: 10
```

The text file is supposed to look like this:

```
smallest
8 7 3
10
```

So i am running the program, and it is giving me an error:

```
initHydraHeads.append(int(stat[i]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '
```

What am i doing wrong in here?

Answer (score 0):

The chunk

```
stat = stat.strip()
initHydraHeads = []
for i in range(len(stat)):
    initHydraHeads.append(int(stat[i]))
```

is broken. You iterate over string which contain spaces among digits. And tese spaces break `int()` conversion. It's better to use something like this:

```
heads = [int(x) for x in stat.split()]
```

thus by the way you'll get not only *digits* but whole *numbers*.

Comment: It is working, but wrong output, it is just outputting Result: Hercules slays the hydra after 0 rounds. Every time i test it with different files

Comment: Then it's another mistake. Try to use debugger and see what's wrong